Need help in deploying upgradeable contracts on the Tron network using the TransparentUpgradeableProxy
I am trying to deploy an upgradeable smart contract (using the TransparentUpgradeableProxy pattern) on the Tron network.
I have a smart contract as below (simplified for readability)
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/access/OwnableUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/security/ReentrancyGuardUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/security/PausableUpgradeable.sol";

contract Manager is
    Initializable,
    OwnableUpgradeable,
    ReentrancyGuardUpgradeable,
    PausableUpgradeable
{
    //...
    function initialize(
        address _initialToken,
        address _pauser,
        address _market
    ) public initializer {
        __Ownable_init();
        __ReentrancyGuard_init();
        __Pausable_init();

        require(_pauser != address(0), "Invalid pauser address");
        pauser = _pauser;

        market = _market;

        approvedToken = IERC20(_initialToken);
    }
}

My 2_deploy_manager.js file is as below. This is as per the Tron documentation :
const { deployProxy } = require('@openzeppelin/truffle-upgrades');
const Manager = artifacts.require('Manager');

module.exports = async function (deployer) {
  try {
    // Setup tronbox deployer for proxy compatibility
    deployer.trufflePlugin = true;

    const initialToken = process.env.ERC20_CONTRACT_ADDRESS;
    const pauserAddress = process.env.PAUSER_ADDRESS;
    const marketAddress = "TTQk7i9JTraPUudFFESqWxUdRvhWfJp";

    // Deploy proxy with initialization parameters
    const instance = await deployProxy(
      Manager, 
      [initialToken, pauserAddress, marketAddress], 
      { 
        deployer,
        initializer: 'initialize' 
      }
    );

    console.info('Manager Proxy deployed at:', instance.address);

    // Verify deployment by calling a view function
    const manager = await Manager.deployed();
    const deployedPauser = await tokenManager.pauser();
    console.info('Deployed pauser address:', deployedPauser);

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Manager proxy deployment error:', error);
  }
};

My package.json is as below:
{
    "dependencies": {
      "@openzeppelin/contracts": "^4.9.6",
      "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable": "^4.9.6",
      "@openzeppelin/truffle-upgrades": "^1.21.0",
      "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
      "ethers": "^4.0.49",
      "tronweb": "^6.0.0"
    }
  }

Finally my tronbox.js is updated as below
nile: {
  privateKey: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY,
  userFeePercentage: 100,
  feeLimit: 1500000000, // Increased fee limit
  fullHost: "https://nile.trongrid.io",
  network_id: "201910292",
  confirmation: 3, // Wait for more block confirmations
  timeoutBlocks: 200,
  deployer: {
    trufflePlugin: true // Set this to true for deployProxy compatibility
  }

I get this error when running a deployment
Manager proxy deployment error: Error: invalid address (argument="address", value="TXYZopYRdj2D9XRtbG411XZZ3kM5VkAeBf", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=address/5.7.0) (argument="_initialToken", value="TXYZopYRdj2D9XRtbG411XZZ3kM5VkAeBf", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.7.0)
    at Logger.makeError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tronbox/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:269:28)
    at Logger.throwError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tronbox/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:281:20)
    at Logger.throwArgumentError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tronbox/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:285:21)
    at AddressCoder.Coder._throwError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tronbox/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/src.ts/coders/abstract-coder.ts:68:16)
    at AddressCoder.encode (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tronbox/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/src.ts/coders/address.ts:22:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/tronbox/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/src.ts/coders/array.ts:71:19
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at pack (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tronbox/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/src.ts/coders/array.ts:54:12)
    at TupleCoder.encode (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tronbox/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/src.ts/coders/tuple.ts:54:20)
    at AbiCoder.encode (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tronbox/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/src.ts/abi-coder.ts:111:15)
    at ABICoder.encodeParameters (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tronbox/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/index.js:127:27)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/tronbox/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/index.js:463:20
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object._encodeMethodABI (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tronbox/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/index.js:462:8)
    at getInitializerData (/home/Desktop/demo/scsc/node_modules/@openzeppelin/truffle-upgrades/src/utils/initializer-data.ts:13:56)
    at deployProxy (/home/Desktop/demo/scsc/node_modules/@openzeppelin/truffle-upgrades/src/deploy-proxy.ts:37:34)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at module.exports (/home/Desktop/demo/sc/migrations/2_deploy_token_manager.js:14:22) {
  reason: 'invalid address (argument="address", value="TXYZopYRdj2D9XRtbG411XZZ3kM5VkAeBf", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=address/5.7.0)',
  code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
  argument: '_initialToken',
  value: 'TXYZopYRdj2D9XRtbG411XZZ3kM5VkAeBf'
}

If I use TronWeb to convert the address to Hex as below
const TronWeb = require('tronweb').default;
...
const tronWeb = new TronWeb({
      fullHost: 'https://nile.trongrid.io',
      privateKey: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY // Add your private key here
    });

    const initialTokenHex = tronWeb.address.toHex(process.env.ERC20_CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
    const pauserAddressHex = tronWeb.address.toHex(process.env.PAUSER_ADDRESS);
    const marketAddressHex = tronWeb.address.toHex("TTQk7i9JTraPUuTmoESqWxUdRvhWfJp");

...
I get the following console.error
Running migration: 2_deploy_token_manager.js
    Manager proxy deployment error: TypeError: TronWeb is not a constructor;

Besides I would assume that the address conversion to hex

may not be required
may be handled anyway by tronbox

I am not sure how to deploy the Manager.sol and its proxy for use in my DAPP. Do I rewrite my 2_deploy..script? If so how?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
